# Entity Framework 6, Transaction Scope, Context and SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, transactionscope, savechanges

Question pertains to transaction scope and `context.SaveChanges()`. If I'm processing a million records with a `foreach`, and I save after every, let's say, 1000 records by calling `context.SaveChanges()` inside a transaction scope and something fails after 10 000 have been processed and `SaveChanges()` called, will already saved data be rolled back?
example:

```
using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope( TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)))
{
    int counter = 0;
    using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
    { 
        foreach(var item in context.Items)
        {
            //process item
            if(counter >= 1000)
            {
                context.SaveChanges(); //if fail here, will already saved changes be rolled back?
                counter = 0
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    ts.Complete();//what about here?
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is just an example. But if you are about to save a million rows you better look at some more efficient solutions. For example https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities#batch-insert-entities  (which i maintain) will insert that in 10s-20s on a decent computer.

Answer (score 4):

The transaction scope takes precedence as long as the `DbContext` is enrolled in it, which it is by default.

Thus, if you don't call `TransactionScope.Complete` (e.g. because a `DbContext`-related exception throws you outside of the `using` block), *everything* will be rolled back as you expect.  I encourage you to simply try it (best with a profiler on the side to monitor what's going on exactly).

In short, every `SaveChanges` will hit the database, but won't commit.

Comment: that is interesting you say this. Even if "rollback" is not called on the transaction?

Comment: @Dee When you leave the `using` block of the TS, [`TS.Dispose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.dispose) is called implicitly (those are the semantics of `using` in C#). As you can see in the documentation, if `Complete` wasn't called, then the ambient transaction is rolled back. In fact, there is no "Rollback" method on [TS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Transactions.TransactionScope). EF also supports explicit transactions instead of TS if you prefer, which is sometimes recommended for various reasons.